# Publishing MQTT messages from a Python script on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt

I am trying to configure a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian, Jessie) to send temperature data from a DS18B20 sensor to my MQTT broker.

I have installed mosquitto, mosquitto-clients, and python-mosquitto. I have also installed paho-mqtt.

Mosquitto seems to be working fine; I can publish from the command line but I can not get ANY python script I've written or found to publish or subscribe.

Why does this work from the command line,

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.0.21 -d -t test/test -m "Hello world!"
```

while this script does not?

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

 import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

 # set up the mqtt client
 mqttc = mqtt.Client("python_pub")

 # the server to publish to, and corresponding port
 mqttc.connect("192.168.0.21", 1883)

 # the topic to publish to, and the message to publish
 mqttc.publish("test/test", "Hello world!")

 # establish a two-second timeout
 mqttc.loop(2)
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Experimenting, I found that by changing the IP in the script to that of the Pi itself, I CAN publish MQTT that is received by the Pi. The Pi can also receive messages published to it. I still, however, can't publish from a script to an external broker. So now I'm thinking it's a broker issue...

Comment: what do you mean the script does not work ? What exactly happening ?

Comment: The code as posted works for me (it's not great, but it works). Please update the question with more details about what doesn't work when you try

Comment: When publishing from the command line the message is received by my MQTT broker. However, when attempting to publish from that (or any other) script, no messages are received by my broker. Also, when running "mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.21 -d -t test/test" from a seperate SSH window, the raspbery pi itself does not receive the messages from the scritpts.

Comment: no error messages from the python scripts?

Comment: Nothing. No errors. Nothing in the mosquito log.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment, the code you posted does work, but for publishing a [single](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#single) message this form is better

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish

publish.single("test/test", "Hello world!", hostname="192.168.0.21")
```

Comment: Good stuff, I'll add it to my notes. With my current setup, however, this script hangs and no message is received by either my broker or the raspberry pi itself.