# Paho MQTT client on Raspberry Pi never publishes

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733589/publishing-mqtt-messages-from-a-python-script-on-a-raspberry-pi), the publish from Raspberry Pi with Paho MQTT with Python simply does not go through. The `mosquitto_` commands on the other hand work perfectly.

This one does not work.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
publish.single(topic='temp/temp',payload='random',hostname='192.168.1.105')
```

This one works.

```
mosquito_pub -h 192.168.1.105 -t temp/temp -l
random
```

Please guide me what is missing?

Comment: The python code you've posted works (with the hostname changed) against my local broker. Is there any output to the console when you run it? What version of the paho lib? What version of python?

Comment: No; nothing at all. That's the disappointing part. I did `pip install paho-mqtt` and python is 2.7.9

Comment: Until some one figures out what is the issue, here is my work-around, `os.system("mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.105 -t temp/temp -f msg")`

Comment: Works for me from both Pi3/python 2.7.9/Jessie and from Windows, using the public broker messagesight.demos.ibm.com. You can check that the publish succeeded by first browsing to  http://m2m.demos.ibm.com/mqttclient/, click Connect, and then subscribe to temp/temp - so it appears that the issue is specific to you/your environment. Describe how you know that one works and the other doesn't. BTW no output to the console is what you would expect from your Python script - it publishes then exits, so absence of console output is no indicator of failure. Did you do sudo pip install paho-mqtt?

Comment: If the issue was specific to my environment, how did `mosquitto_pub` work? In fact, `mosquitto_pub` works on command line and through `os.system()`. By no output on command line, I meant to say that, the command never completes to see an output on the console, etc.

Comment: > "if the issue was specific to my environment...?" Because that python code works for others against different brokers. Did you try using the python against the public mqtt server, see if it works. If it works then suspicion is around your broker or network. If it doesn't work then suspicion is around your Pi. As I said in previous comment, the two lines of python you posted don't produce any output on the console, so lack of output doesn't indicate failure.

Comment: @cogitoergosum What broker are you using and what version is it?

Answer (score 0):

Having worked this out for several other questions I'm going to guess you have a old version of mosquitto that only supports MQTT v3.1 not v3.1.1.

This should fix things.

```
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
publish.single(topic='temp/temp',payload='random',hostname='192.168.1.105', protocol=mqtt.MQTTv31)
```