# Publishing uplink messages from python script to TTN (the things network) simulating nodes

Tags: python, iot

For testing purposes I am trying to publish MQTT messages (uplink) to TTN (the things network) from a python script on my normal computer. This should simulate an uplink from a node.

Based on examples I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38733589/publishing-mqtt-messages-from-a-python-script-on-a-raspberry-pi) and on a [blog](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/publishing-messages-mqtt-client/) I composed the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import paho.mqtt.client as paho

#settings
app_id = "<Application ID from the TTN console>"
access_key = "ttn-account-v2.etcetcetcetcetc.."

broker="eu.thethings.network"
port=1883

def on_publish(client,userdata,result):
    print("data published \n")
    print(client,userdata,result)
    pass

def on_log(mqttc, obj, level, string):
    print(string)

#setup
client = paho.Client()
client.username_pw_set(app_id,access_key)

#callbacks
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_log = on_log

#establish connection
client.connect(broker,port)
client.loop_start()

#publish
ret= client.publish("applicationID/bulb1","on",qos=1)
ret.wait_for_publish()
```

When being run it outputs

```
Received CONNACK (0, 0)
Received PUBACK (Mid: 1)
data published
```

However when I check the TTN page of my application I don't see the data.

Anyone any suggestions why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still having this issue two months later, however I just had a similar issue and found the answer.

First of all you want to use the "ttn" python library instead of the MQTT paho library, as it makes connecting a lot easier. You can find that under the following link:

https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/applications/python/api-reference.html#mqttclient

If you follow through their guide, you will at first also encounter the same issue you are having here, as they do not explain how to properly send a downlink message and provide no examples of it.

The following is what you want to do in order to send a message down while using the ttn library:

```
client.send("device_id", base64.encodebytes(bytes("DATA YOU WANT TO SEND", 'utf-8')).decode(), port=1, sched="replace")
```